# Shorten the cloudpage URL and write SMS tracking information to Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, cloudpagesurl, tracking

I have successfully created a cloudpage and used it to track which users click on the cloudpage URL for messages sent through SMS, but I think the generated link is too long, which will affect the user experience. Therefore, I want to shorten the URL, know how to shorten it, and write the ID of the user who clicked to access the URL into the Data Extension?

I tried to use ampscript to track and shorten the URL. I successfully shortened the URL, but I found that clicking on the shortened URL did not write the click record into Data Extension, so I did not succeed in tracking

My code in SMS：

```
%%[ var @Id, @shortenUrl, @bitlyUrl, @link
set @Id = AttributeValue('Id')
set @link = URLEncode(CloudPagesURL(2343,'Id',@Id))
set @bitlyUrl = 'https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN&longUrl='
set @shortenUrl = HTTPGet(Concat(@bitlyUrl,@link,"&format=txt")) ]%%
%%=RedirectTo(v(@shortenUrl))=%%
```

My code in cloudpage：

```
<div class="cta-wrapper">
 
%%[ var @Id
SET @Id = RequestParameter('Id')
SET @value = upsertData("test_SMS",1,"Id",@Id,'Date clicked',NOW())]%%
<a href="https://www.meadjohnson.com.tw/">Click here!</a>

</div>
```

Comment: I believe bitly removes utm params unless its paid for

Comment: Have you tried outputting `@Id` in the CloudPage? To see if the parameter is passed correctly. Also, have you generally tried to hardcode `@Id` in the CloudPage and test if UpsertData working correctly?

Comment: Yes, Niko, I have solved this problem, and now I can successfully track and shorten the link

Comment: If you meant that @Id is passed correctly and UpasertData is fine as well. Then, it might worth checking with bitly if they are really removing UTMs and generally, it is not recommended to use Bitly v3 now, since it is should not be already working by now since v4 has been introduced a while ago.

Comment: I have checked that the UTM has not been deleted, and the access data has been successfully written into Data Extension. At present, we plan to adopt this scheme. What are the disadvantages of bitly V3? If this method is adopted, what should we pay attention to?

Comment: You are risking that your solution would break at any moment. Bitly API v3 should not even be available now, idk why it works for you but it is not recommended to continue using it. Check out [this](https://dev.bitly.com/docs/getting-started/migrating-from-v3/) and [this](https://support.bitly.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004395631-Am-I-connecting-to-Bitly-using-the-latest-version-of-the-Bitly-API-) articles.

Comment: Hi Niko, thank you for your reminder. If I want to use bitly API V4 instead of V3, how can I modify my code? Can you give me some advice?

Comment: Hi Niko，Can you give me some suggestions on code modification? Because I don't know the difference between V3 and V4, thank you

Comment: There are plenty of different available resources on StackExchange and official Bitly API documentation, you can find them yourself and use them as a reference to create your own code.